# WPF: nested designData

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have the following simplified element in a page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyContext}}"
      d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MyContextSampleData.xaml}">
```

The MyContext class has some properties that are references, not just simple data. One such property for that class is `public MyReferenceType MyReferenceProperty`.

I have built sample data for both MyContext and MyReferenceType.

Here is the MyReferenceTypeSampleData.xaml:

```
<data:MyReferenceType
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Data;assembly=MyNamespace.Data"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

 MyValueProperty0="True"
 MyValueProperty1="123"
 MyValueProperty2="abc"
/>
```

and MyContextSampleData.xaml is where I am stumped.

```
<data:MyContext
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Data;assembly=MyNamespace.Data"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

 MyReferenceProperty="{d:DesignData SampleData/MyReferenceTypeSampleData.xaml}"
/>
```

`MyReferenceProperty="{d:DesignData SampleData/MyReferenceTypeSampleData.xaml}"` is of course wrong. I am trying to do the equivalent of what this does for setting `d:DataContext`. I want the property to be set in the sample data to the sampledata xaml.

Is this possible and if not, what would be the common workaround. Surely this is a typical use case because mock data is rarely just value types. Anyone know how to handle this?